# Google maps with JavaScript only displaying 2 maps when i have 8 variables

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi guys i'm trying to display different maps in different pages but all with the same JavaScript file.
I did the same code from every map (changing variables) but only the first 2 are working. 
I think it's because the JavaScript file gets the ID from the first page and then it doesn't search other pages for the other ID's so it says they are null and doesn't find them.
How do I make it search the ID's in different HTML pages?

Thanks in advance.
Here's the code:

```
window.onload = (function () {

var lidertel = {lat: 43.300829, lng: -3.032376};
var ametsa = {lat: 43.306208, lng: -3.049617};
var ekin = {lat: 43.235692, lng: -3.008844};
var norbisca = {lat: 43.301795, lng: -2.947333};
var menesianos = {lat: 42.821056, lng: -2.799419};
var goval = {lat: 43.250875, lng: -2.896717};
var blueForce = {lat: 43.260901, lng: -2.926113};
var azulMarino = {lat: 43.260785, lng: -2.928851};


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-lidertel'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: lidertel,
        });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: lidertel,
        map: map
    });


    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-ametsa'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: ametsa,
    });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ametsa,
        map: map2
    });


    var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-ekin'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: ekin
    });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ekin,
        map: map3
    });


    var map4 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-norbisca'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: norbisca
    });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: norbisca,
        map: map4
    });


    var map5 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-menesianos'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: menesianos
    });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: menesianos,
        map: map5
    });


    var map6 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-goval'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: goval
    });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: goval,
        map: map6
    });


    var map7 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-blueForce'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: blueForce
    });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: blueForce,
        map: map7
    });


    var map8 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-azulMarino'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: azulMarino
    });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: azulMarino,
        map: map8
    });
});
```

Example of one of the html:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Map -->
<div id="map-ekin" class="map-profile">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback"
            defer>
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is not a good practice to post your API key

Comment: Does the javascript developer console give you some errors?

Comment: The gmap async script namely `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"
            async defer>
    </script>`
should be just once in your whole page. every time it loads the `google.maps.*` is populated causing weird behavior

Comment: yes it does
js?key=&callback=initMap:98 Uncaught Vb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Vb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m...&callback=initMap:144:59"}

Comment: js?key=&callback=initMap:99 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. 
with this one i tested taking out the script at the index and it doesnt work. (have a map in the footer with the api key called 
js?key=&callback=initMap:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null 
at Object._.vg (js?key=&callback=initMap:88) 
at new Ag (js?key=&callback=initMap:90) 
at map.js:40

Comment: and in the one page that works when i take out the second <script> i had it displays it fine the 2 maps but i still get 2 erros:
js?key=&callback=initMap:98 Uncaught Vb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Vb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…&callback=initMap:144:59"}

js?key=AIzaSyA3TYDuBAWuV3XOnoq-XaIlkhN4qJxfu5s&callback=initMap:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.vg (js?key=&callback=initMap:88)
    at new Ag (js?key=&callback=initMap:90)
    at map.js:40

Comment: The error says you added the script multiple times in the whole page. remove the duplicates and it should work

Comment: it works the same as before. In the one page (with the first 2 variables) it works. the others dont. The map in the footer is shown but the other one is not. 
The script is only getting called once in the footer as a php include.

Comment: What i think what's happening is that the different ID's are in different html pages and the JS only works in the first page (where the first variables are called)
How do I make it so it finds the other ID's in the other pages?

Comment: @Serrano so you've got 8 pages, each with their own map, but 1 JS file that calls `new google.maps.Map` 8 times, so it loads the map for each page?  Don't do this. Instead pass the ID of the relevant map div into your JS function so it loads just that map.

Comment: @duncan Can you give me an example please?
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's a simple suggestion.  Declare a global variable in the head of each page, with the relevant map ID for that page.

```
<script>
var mapId = 'lidertel';
</script>
```

Then modify your JS file to something like this:

```
window.onload = (function () {
    var coordinates = {
        lidertel:  {lat: 43.300829, lng: -3.032376},
        ametsa: {lat: 43.306208, lng: -3.049617},
        ekin: {lat: 43.235692, lng: -3.008844},
        norbisca: {lat: 43.301795, lng: -2.947333},
        menesianos: {lat: 42.821056, lng: -2.799419},
        goval: {lat: 43.250875, lng: -2.896717},
        blueForce: {lat: 43.260901, lng: -2.926113},
        azulMarino: {lat: 43.260785, lng: -2.928851}
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-' + mapId), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: coordinates[mapId],
        });
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coordinates[mapId],
        map: map
    });
});
```

So it should be able to read that `mapId` variable to get the correct coordinates and the ID of the relevant `<div>`.  You probably need to make sure this file gets loaded after you declare the `mapId` variable.